# Among Us Random Generator

Tags: ruby

I'm having trouble with my code here what it's supposed to do is generate a number from 1 to 6 and than ask you who you think the imposter is after it asks you it waits for input and than checks for the input and the random number that was generated if the input is Red and the random number was 1 it would say that red is the imposter and so on with Orange and 2 Green and 3 Yelow and 4 Cyan with 5 and Black with 6 but the problem is that if you put anything that isn't red EX: Orange it just stops for no reason. What did I do wrong with the code? Please help.

```
susas = rand (1..6)
puts "Who is the imposter?"
sleep (1)
puts "Is it Red, Orange, Green, Yellow, Cyan, Or Black (use capital format EX:Red)"
answr = gets.chomp
if answr == "Red" && susas == 1
  puts "Red was the imposter"
elsif answr == "Red" && susas != 1
  puts "Red was not the imposter you failed"
  if answr == "Orange" && susas == 2
    puts "Orange was the imposter"
  elsif answr == "Orange" && susas != 2
    puts "Orange was not the imposter you failed"
    if answr == "Green" && susas == 3
      puts "Green was the imposter"
    elsif answr == "Green" && susas != 3
      puts "Green was not the imposter you failed"
      if answr == "Yellow" && susas == 4
        puts "Yellow was the imposter"
      elsif answr == "Yellow" && susas != 4
        puts "Yellow was not the imposter you failed"
        if answr == "Cyan" && susas == 5
          puts "Cyan was the imposter"
        elsif answr == "Cyan" && susas != 5
          puts "Cyan was not the imposter you failed"
          if answr == "Black" && susas == 6
            puts "Black was the imposter"
          elsif answr == "Black" && susas != 6
            puts "Black was not the imposter you failed"
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is a repl.it link https://repl.it/@Student_Aiden_K/SmoothFaithfulComputerscience#main.rb

Comment: If you click the link you should see the code Idk how to format the code thats why I dont have it on the question.

Comment: Suppose `answr` is not red. Then trace through your code line by line and take a look at which lines will execute in that case. I have a feeling it's fewer than you might be thinking.

Comment: Silvio Mayolo I do not know what you mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if you put anything that isn't red EX: Orange it just stops for no reason. What did I do wrong with the code?

You have two main branches:

```
if answr == "Red" && susas == 1
  puts "Red was the imposter"
elsif answr == "Red" && susas != 1
  puts "Red was not the imposter you failed"
  # anything else
end
```

The other colors are all under the `elsif` branch but Ruby will not reach them because `answr == "Red"` will be `false` for all colors beside red.

What you want is more `elsif`'s on the same level:

```
if answr == "Red" && susas == 1
  puts "Red was the imposter"
elsif answr == "Red" && susas != 1
  puts "Red was not the imposter you failed"
elsif answr == "Orange" && susas == 2
  puts "Orange was the imposter"
elsif answr == "Orange" && susas != 2
  puts "Orange was not the imposter you failed"
# ...
end
```

Needless to say, there's a lot of repetition in your code. You should try to reduce that.

You could for example add a hash to map color names to numbers:

```
colors = {
  'Red' => 1, 'Orange' => 2, 'Green' => 3,
  'Yellow' => 4, 'Cyan' => 5, 'Black' => 6
}
```

Then fetch the number for the given answer:

```
answer = gets.chomp
number = colors[answer]
```

And have just one `if` to check whether it is correct or not:

```
if number == susas
  puts "#{answer} was the imposter"
else
  puts "#{answer} was not the imposter you failed"
end
```